Does the initial value problem $x\,\mathrm dt + (t-1)\,\mathrm dx = 0$ with $x(t=0)=1$ have a solution?
I tried solving this IVP by separating variables:
\begin{cases}x\,\mathrm dt + (t-1)\,\mathrm dx = 0\\ x(t=0)=1
\end{cases}
$$\int \frac{\mathrm dx}{x} = - \int \frac{\mathrm dt}{t-1}$$
$$\ln(x) = \ln\left(\frac{1}{t-1}\right) + c$$
$$x = e^c \cdot \frac{1}{t-1}$$
Now plugging in the initial value $x(t=0) = 1$:
$$1 = e^c \cdot\frac{1}{-1}$$
$$c \in \emptyset$$
So does this mean the IVP has no solution? Is this because at $t = 1$ the function $x$ is undefined? I think that cannot be the case, since if the given initial value was negative, e.g. $x(t=0) = -1$, this problem would have an answer.

The mistake here is with the antiderivative of $1/x$.
$$\int\frac{\mathrm dx}{x}=\ln|x|+c$$
So, you instead proceed
$$\ln|x|=\ln\left(\frac1{|t-1|}\right)+c$$
Then,
$$|x|=\frac{e^c}{|t-1|}$$
or
$$x=\frac{\pm e^c}{t-1}$$
So, you can just call $\pm e^c$ some constant $k$ (if you want, assume $k\neq0$). Then,
$$x=\frac{k}{t-1}$$
You should be able to continue from here.
Hope this helps. :)

Substitution $x\to-x$ also satisfies the equation:
$$(-x)\mathrm dt+(t-1)\mathrm d(-x)=0$$
which means, if $x(t)=f(t)$ is the solution, $x(t)=-f(t)$ is, too.
So with your solution, adding a negative sign and
$$x=\mathrm e^c\cdot\frac1{1-t}$$
is also a solution. Your initial condition $x\mid_{t=0}=1$ can be taken to this solution, in which you can find $c=0$, and the final solution is
$$x=\frac{1}{1-t}$$

In a small neighbourhood of $(t_0,x_0)=(0,1)$, you have $x>0$ and $t-1<0$ so $|x|=x$ and $|t-1|=1-t$, hence:
$$x=\frac{e^c}{1-t} $$
Plugging the initial condition, you get:
$$1=e^c\implies c=0 $$

Ahh, I think I understand my mistake. The integral should equatate to $\int \frac{1}{x}dx = ln(|x|) + c$ instead of $ln(x) + c$. Thanks!

@Gustamons yes,  and you can drop the absolute value seeing what happens in a neighbourhood of $(0,1)$
